# 2 Minor Crossbrowser CSS Issues. Background images not displaying in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, google-chrome

I am working on the redesign of my website http://square1dev.com. In the sidebar however, I am having some issues making it look correct in Google Chrome. Issues are:

Categories Title (h2 Background Image) - There is supposed to be a small little line to the right side of the word "Categories". Safari and Firefox show this, Chrome however doesn't.

Categories List (li list-style-image) - Each list item is supposed to have a small image of Right Angle Quotes (»). Again, Safari and Firefox show this, Chrome not so much.

Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: My chrome shows everything you mention ... Chrome version 3.0.195.38, OS WinXP

Comment: ... and I'm in Firefox 3.5.7 on Windows Vista and I _don't_ see those things

Comment: See both, Chrome 4.0.249.43, Ubuntu (Karmic)

Comment: This is almost certainly a caching issue, as suggested below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome can have some weird CSS caching behavior, based on comments and my viewing it in half a dozen browsers, I have to suggest blowing away your Chrome cache and trying again...I've run into this several times where it'll lodge a stylesheet in cache and not let go.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I will play around testing with some other computers.