# Preload Image not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load an image on preload. It's working fine with IE and Firefox but not with Chrome. I'm simply doing this:

```
    var t1 = "<div id='waiting' style='filter:alpha(opacity=50); z-index:9990; position:fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: visible; opacity: 0.5; background-color:white;'>";
    t1 += "<img src='img/loader_36.gif' alt='waiting' style='z-index:9999; position:fixed; top:40%; left:45%;width:36px; height:36px;' /></div>";
    $('body').append(t1);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var t1 = "<div id='waiting' style='filter:alpha(opacity=50); z-index:9990; position:fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: visible; opacity: 0.5; background-color:white;'>";
t1 += "<img src='http://lorempixel.com/400/200' alt='waiting' style='z-index:9999; position:fixed; top:40%; left:45%;width:36px; height:36px;' /></div>";
$('body').append(t1);
```

tested on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wW2D/), it works fine on chrome

1. what version of jquery do you use?
2. version of chrome?
3. is image src correct in chrome?

Comment: yes,its working fine in this case but i am talking about preload...
my problem is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355133/pre-loaded-images-not-displaying-in-chrome

Comment: Then why not use the same solution? You should not use dom insertion as preload

Answer (score 0):

Make the Object of the image which is not loaded.

```
var _myImage = new Image(400,200) //height and width of the image
_myImage.src = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200"; // image source (path)
```

Put this code in the page where you want to use